# Lotus: prevent from opening document while it is opened by other user

Tags: locking, lotus-notes, document

Is it possible to prevent from opening a document by user while it is opened/edited by another user? I know there is a locking functionality, so I can't edit a document when it is edited ba another, but I can open it. I need to prevent from OPENING a document, not only prevent from editing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying I would not recommend this. There are too many things that could go wrong.  That said, however, you could have code in the QueryOpen script check a hidden field to see if anyone has set it. If it is set, then the script sets `Continue = false` and exits. Otherwise, it sets the hidden field to `@Username`. The QueryClose script can clear the field. The most obvious thing that can go wrong, of course, is that QueryClose never runs. The next most obvious in a Notes/Domino environment is that two replicas of the database may exist, in which case the above strategy only works within a given replica so multiple people can still edit the document, and you'll probably start getting replication conflicts.

Comment: OK, thank you, of course you're right.
But tell me how to solve the problem of sharing documents.
In my database I have a documents where multiply users adding some notes into RichText fields, so when 2 or more users edits the same document (for example in different replicas) after saving it there will be replication conflicts, right?
Do you have any ideas how to solve a case like that?

Comment: Have the users create response documents that inherit a unique key from the main document.  Create a flat view that selects the response documents and is categorized on the unique key. To show the responses in the main document, add your new view as an embedded view on the form and use the show-single-category feature.

Comment: Also, your question mentioned that you know about the locking feature in Notes, but you wanted to prevent users from even opening documents. Now you're talking about replication conflicts (or save conflicts, if it is all on one server), but opening documents does not cause replication conflicts. Perhaps you should make it a little bit clearer why you don't think the existing locking feature is sufficient.